# Je me tape, je me suis tapé, je vais taper

Tags: expressions

J’aurais besoin de comprendre la différence entre « Je me tape », « Je me suis tapé », « Je vais taper ». D'abord j'ai pensé qu'il ne s'agissait que de « frapper », ensuite je me suis rendu compte qu'il y a d'autres sens. Quels sont ces  sens ? S'il vous plait, donnez des exemples explicatifs pour ces sens.

Comment: Il doit tout de même y avoir quelque complément qui pourrait orienter la comprenette, non ? Je sais pas moi, la voisine, trois vermouth-cassis, Federer, une Ferrari, 0/20 ... ?

Comment: Ne pas oublier "je m'en tape" comme dans par exemple : "Cette question, je m'en tape".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A** Je me tape, Je me suis tapé

« Se taper » appartient à la langue populaire et à la langue familière ([TLFi, III. − Empl. pronom. réfl .A](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taper)).

**I** C'est un verbe qui signifie souvent absorber de la nourriture, des boissons, des pâtisseries, etc. L'idée dans l'utilisation de ce verbe est qu'il s'agit de l'absorption de quelque chose de substantiel en volume et/ou en gout.

- Elle s'est tapé une bouteille de champagne en un rien de temps puis elle a disparu.

**II** Il est aussi employé souvent pour signifier « faire un travail désagréable ou quelque chose de harassant ».

- Je me suis tapé la vaisselle du banquet et après ça, le repassage.
- J'ai dû me taper 10 km à pied; la voiture est en panne dans les bois.

**III** Il a aussi le sens de « posséder charnellement » ;

- Le samedi soir, il se tape sa petite voisine pendant que sa femme est au travail.

**IV** Ce verbe, toujours dans le même registre de langue, signifie aussi « faire une croix sur quelque chose », c'est à dire « se passer de quelque chose » ; il est surtout employé dans l'expression « pouvoir se taper ».

- Pour des résultats rapides et sans fautes, je peux me taper. C'est le dernier de leurs soucis.

**B** Je vais taper

On ne peux donner que deux sens à cette forme.

1/ (registre courant)Lorsque quelqu'un se trouve devant la porte d'une habitation ou d'une pièce qui est occupée, « je vais taper » signifie « je vais frapper à la porte. ».

2/(registre plutôt vulgaire) Dans le contexte d'une querelle, lorsque quelqu'un (un homme plus particulièrement) dis « je vais taper », cela signifie assez souvent qu'il menace d'user de sa force physique contre son adversaire. C'est une façon d'avertir quelqu'un que s'il persiste dans son comportement hostile, il va recevoir des coups, mais c'est une  façon assez fanfaronne de donner un tel avertissement. Parfois, ce sera tout simplement le signal qu'il va en venir aux mains.

Comment: "***B** Je vais taper : on ne peux donner que deux sens à cette forme*": et "taper quelqu'un* (pour emprunter de l'argent) ?

Comment: @OneMoreTimeButAnonimously Oui, mais il faut alors un complément : je vais **te** taper, je vais **le** taper, je vais en taper **un**, je vais taper **quelqu'un**, etc.

Comment: Dans un documentaire sur les escroqueries en Afrique, j'ai entendu des gens dire "taper quelqu'un" dans le sens arnaquer ou dérober quelqu'un. Sans nécessairement notion de violence dans l'acte (cela peut se produire à distance, par email par exemple). Je ne me souviens plus du pays en question, mais je ne l'ai jamais entendu dans ce sens en France.